# Java class with member variable of type Object

Tags: java, generics

Is it frowned upon to store a generic `Object` class within a class as a member variable? I have a use case where I have a Java class with the following member variables:

```
public class Request {
     private String id;
     private Object payload;
}
```

The payload needs to hold many different types of objects. For this example i'll just show two.

```
public class Entity {
     private String entityId;
     private String name;
}

public class User {
     private String uid;
     private String firstname; 
     private String lastname;
}
```

Ultimately, I need to create a list of `Request` objects `List<Request>` that can support internally storing generic payload objects. Using the Java generic `T` for the `payload` member variable in the `Request` class does not seem like a good approach because I need to be able to construct a list of `Request` objects that hold many different internal payload object types. What is the best way to handle this in Java?

Comment: You can use List<Payload<?>> without specifiying concrete type. It'll be as good as Object but might make your code look better in other cases. But it's up to your case, there's nothing to frown upon on Object, it's perfectly legal code.

Comment: I would make an abstract AbstractEntity class, with the String id. I'd have a getter for the id and another for a payload. Then I'd have specific Entities inherit from AbstractEntity.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is still better to use generics in this case, rather than an `Object`. Since you will need to store many different `Request` objects which can contain different types of payloads, simply create a super class (or interface) which all of your payload classes inherit from, so that you can create your list as something like `List<Request<Payload>>` where each class (such as `Entity` and `User`) inherits from this `Payload` super class. This at least gives you the added benefit of your `Request` object not being able to contain just any `Object` as the payload, but rather an instance of the `Payload` class